# hover not working on child divs

Tags: html, css, web

here is HTML

```
    <div class="songsdetails">
        <a href="#" id="c">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="songsnumbers">
                    <span>1 -</span><br>
                </div>
            </div>                                  
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="songsname">
                    <span>Ay Putar Hattan Ty</span><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="songduration">
                    <span>4:56</span><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
            </div>
```

I want all classes in my a tag to change color if any divisions gets mouse hover. but it isn't working Here's css:

```
.songsdetails:hover songsnumbers songsname songsduration
{
color:black;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing class selector since you're selecting classes, and separation since these are essentially 3 different selection rules:

```
.songsdetails:hover .songsnumbers, 
.songsdetails:hover .songsname,
.songsdetails:hover .songsduration {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following CSS:

```
.songsdetails:hover .songsnumbers,
.songsdetails:hover .songsname, 
.songsdetails:hover .songduration {
    color: black;
}
```

You are missing dot (which references class), also separate them with a comma:

```css
.songsdetails:hover .songsnumbers,
.songsdetails:hover .songsname,
.songsdetails:hover .songduration {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="songsdetails">
  <a href="#" id="c">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="songsnumbers">
        <span>1 -</span>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="songsname">
        <span>Ay Putar Hattan Ty</span>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <div class="songduration">
        <span>4:56</span>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

well you forgot to use class selector properly first ..  they have a 'dot' before their names.

one quick solution can be

```
.songsdetails:hover [class^=song]
{
color: black;
}
```

what it does is any child of .songsdetail whose classname start with 'song' will be affected